# Substitute substring in cmd window

Tags: string, batch-file, cmd

I have the following string in a batch file script:

```
ABCE#$1 TroubleMaker[FFFFF A=MyCountry US=1 CA=1 JP=1 EU=1
```

and it's stored in _var,when I do 
`set _var=%_var:* A=%` - it cuts all the characters before `" A"` (including the 'A') and i'm left with `=MyCountry US=1 CA=1 JP=1 EU=1`

how can I change the `set` command to cut also the `=` mark from the string?

tried `set _var=%_var:*==%` - didn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "string=ABCE#$1 TroubleMaker[FFFFF A=MyCountry US=1 CA=1 JP=1 EU=1"

FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%s IN ("%string%") DO SET "string=%%t"
ECHO "%string%"
GOTO :EOF
```

This assumes that you want to delete up to and including the initial <kbd>=</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

The `=` disturbs the substring replacement syntax, because it contains a `=` on its own.

---

You could go for the following work-around:

```
set _var=%_var:* A=%
set _var=%_var:~1%
```

The second line constitutes the substring expansion syntax (type `set /?` for details), which splits off the first character, that is supposed to be a `=`.

This of course works only if the `=` immediately follows the `A` substring.

---

You can check whether the first character is `=` before removing it, like:

```
set _var=%_var:* A=%
if "%_var:~,1%"=="=" set _var=%_var:~1%
```

---

If you just want to search for the (first) `=` character and to ignore the `A` substring, you could establish a loop structure like this:

```
:LOOP
if "%_var%"=="" goto :END
if "%_var:~,1%"=="=" (
    set _var=%_var:~1%
    goto :END
) else (
    set _var=%_var:~1%
    goto :LOOP
)
:END
```

This cuts off the first character and checks whether it is a `=`. If it is, the remaining string is stored in `_var` and the loop is left; if not, the loop continues checking the next character. The first line is inserted to not hang in case the string does not contain a `=` character.

Comment: Thanks
my problem is that the 'A' substring is not always there, it's there about 90% of the time, but not 100%.. while the '=' substring 100% will be there..
I'm already doing what you suggested (leaving the '=' and removing it with ~1 - but looking for a better way that will work 100% of the time) @aschipfl

Comment: You're welcome! take also a look at [Magoo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34559887/5047996); it does not use substring expansion but `for /F`, and its performance is for sure better than my `goto` loop structure...

Comment: you answer run pretty fine for me, it's no expert to running-time issue, but if i'll run this solution on a weak computer - will Magoo answer will preform better?
@aschipfl

Comment: In general, yes; you will notice the difference in case you run the code multiple times in a loop for example, with numerous iterations; actually I would do it using Magoo's method; in my answer I just wanted to demonstrate how to do it using the substring syntax, because you are actually asking about that...

Comment: Just a side-note: in case the string is `abc==def`, my method removes the *first* `=` only and returns `=def`, but Magoo's method returns `def`...